# EF relationship issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to make entity relationship between two entities, but getting inner exception:

First entity:

```
public class DataSourceParam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DataSourceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int SelectOptionId { get; set; }

    public virtual DataSource DataSource { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SelectOption> SelectOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Second entity:

```
public class SelectOption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SelectOptionId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual DataSourceParam DataSourceParam { get; set; }
}
```

The DataSourceParam can have list of options (SelectOptionId) e.g. user can select apple or pear from the select list.

The SelectOption can be used by multiple DataSourceParam.

What is wrong with my relationship?

Error message:

> Error getting value from 'SelectOptions' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.DataSourceParam_3ED5235781E96F34FEE45416740C9F6A3E9CECC251B67E8CF8BF41B73359766D'."

and the inner exception:

> Invalid column name 'DataSourceParam_Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'DataSourceParam_Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'DataSourceParam_Id'.

**EDIT:**

SelectOption table:

```
Id SelectOptionId Value
1  5              Apple
2  5              Pear
3  5              Grapes
4  7              Monkey
5  7              Dog
6  7              Cat
```

For DataSourceParam with SelectOptionId 7 on the screen user will have displayed dropdown box with the list of animals. I'm not recording this anywhere it will only be used as a parameter for the datasource.

**EDIT2**

If I do it like this it works fine, but I have to create new list of options for every new parameter. Not very elegant, would prefer to reuse lists if possible.

```
    public class DataSourceParam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DataSourceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual DataSource DataSource { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SelectOption> SelectOptions { get; set; }
}

public class SelectOption
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int DataSourceParamId { get; set; }
    public virtual DataSourceParam DataSourceParam { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: welp. without more modelling, EF gets ONE SelectOptionId and is supposed to match a ICollection of SelectOptions with it, and it has no clue how that's supposed to work. Either pull the relationship from the other end (SelectOptions have DataSourceParamId's), or use the modelbuilder to do whatever relationship you like.

Comment: Whats the error message you are getting ?

Comment: what approach of entity framework do you use? code-first, model-first, database-first?

Comment: I use code-first approach but I don't use migration tool to create tables. I do them manually.

Comment: Can you have multiple options selected for each `DataSourceParam` ? for e.g. Apple and Pear?

Comment: yes, but that should not be related as I don't store the selections

Answer (score 0):

If each `DataSourceParam` can only have 1 selected option (i.e. Either Apple or Pear, not both), then change

```
public virtual ICollection<SelectOption> SelectOptions { get; set; }
```

to

```
public virtual SelectOption SelectOption { get; set; }
```

Otherwise, if a `DataSourceParam` can have multiple selections (i.e. Apple and Pear both), then you would need another table to manage that.

Comment: I will edit question to add more details, as from your answer I see misunderstanig

Comment: selectlist is usually passed in a ViewModel and not in your model.

Comment: I would normally use ViewModel for that, but as I'm using mix of MVC and angular it is not recomended to use MVC ViewModels.